# Amazon Redshift error: Mandatory url not present in manifest file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have the following manifest file

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "url": "s3://gcmregtokenvalidation/registrations_invalid_token/registration_master_2017-07-25T10:47:40.049+05:30.gz",
      "mandatory": true
    },
    {
      "url": "s3://gcmregtokenvalidation/registrations_invalid_token/registration_master_2017-07-25T10:47:59.441+05:30.gz",
      "mandatory": true
    },
    {
      "url": "s3://gcmregtokenvalidation/registrations_invalid_token/registration_master_2017-07-25T10:48:19.297+05:30.gz",
      "mandatory": true
    },
    {
      "url": "s3://gcmregtokenvalidation/registrations_invalid_token/registration_master_2017-07-25T10:48:40.277+05:30.gz",
      "mandatory": true
    }
  ]
}
```

and  following copy command

```
COPY registrations_invalid_token
FROM  's3://locationnew/redshiftloader-
manifest/registrations_invalid_token_25_07_2017_11:55:11.manifest' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=XXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXX'
manifest gzip delimiter ',' dateformat 'auto'
FILLRECORD IGNOREBLANKLINES TRIMBLANKS TRUNCATECOLUMNS
MAXERROR 100000 region 'ap-south-1';
```

I got the following exception

> Amazon Invalid operation: Mandatory url is not present in
>   manifest file. Details:
>   -----------------------------------------------   error:  Mandatory url is not present in manifest file.   code:      8001   context:
>   Manifest file
>   location=s3://locationnew/redshiftloader-manifest/registrations_invalid_token_25_07_2017_11:55:11.manifest
>   url=s3://gcmregtokenvalidation/registrations_invalid_token/registration_master_2017-07-25T10:47:40.049+05:30.gz
>   query:     1475619   location:  s3_utility.cpp:337   process:
>   padbmaster [pid=32720]
>   -----------------------------------------------;

Why I am getting such an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Using a Manifest to Specify Data Files](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html) documentation says:

> The optional `mandatory` flag specifies whether COPY should return an error if the file is not found. The default of `mandatory` is `false`. Regardless of any mandatory settings, COPY will terminate if no files are found.

The *Mandatory url is not present in manifest file* error is badly worded, but it *might* be saying that the specified file could not be found on Amazon S3.

You could test it with:

```
aws s3 ls s3://gcmregtokenvalidation/registrations_invalid_token/registration_master_2017-07-25T10:47:40.049+05:30.gz
```

Also, try setting `mandatory` to `false` to see if the error disappears.